# jQuery resize function does only work on window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if the jQuery [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function only works on (a) window? Can't I make use of this function to detect wether a certain element resizes?

For example, the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03pjmc2h/1/) woudn't work now? But would it be possible to actually make it work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Does not work for me: */
  $(".foo").resize(function() {
    alert("yes!");
  });

  /* Does work for me: */
  $(window).resize(function() {
    alert("yes!");
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  ;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer does not support the resize property.</p>

<div class="foo">
  Drag the corner(s) around.
</div>
```

Comment: You will just need to build something yourself.  You complain about functionality that doesn't exist then protest about using jquery UI because you only need the resize functionality???  Build something to monitor it yourself then, its not hard

Comment: @QBM5 That's not my point. My point is that I am looking for an answer wether it is possible to use jQuery to detect wether an element resized, that's all there is to it really. I know the element can resize, because it contains a `height: auto;` by default and the height would change when the content within in it changes. If you're using images as content, you'd probably know what I am talking about.

Comment: There is no event using jquery (base) or plain javascript that will fire an event when an element changes size, the resize event only applies to the window

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible by using this plugin **[JqueryUI Resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)**, code would be as simple as

```
$( ".foo" ).resizable();
```

---

Sample demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#resize-me").resizable();
});
```

```css
#resize-me
{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-55Jz3pBCF8z9jBO1qQ7cIf0L+neuPTD1u7Ytzrp2dqo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="resize-me">
 Resize me
</div>
```

Comment: But it'd be required to include JqueryUI for else this solution wouldn't work? It's not possible with plain jQuery, CSS and HTML? It looks like adding this resizable function would add its own styling to the element or is it just the example?

Comment: @Barrosy yes this would require you to add this plguin, Else if you dont want to use the plugin then you will end up writing the same code as they have written, possibly reinventing the wheel. And the style is added by its css file.. Just by using the js file you will be fine...

Comment: And how would I determine wether the element resized then?

Comment: @Barrosy you can determine with different events available... like on start of resize, on stop of resize, on resize... etc check http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: Okay when I try to make it possible myself this is as far as I can get: https://jsfiddle.net/qu2p5fz9/

Comment: @Barrosy let me check

Comment: @Barrosy https://jsfiddle.net/qu2p5fz9/1/ I think there css is necessary so that we get that icon to click and resize..

Comment: It seems like the script I added did not work either. I don't know wether it was a wrong version or whatever, but now it works.

Comment: Ì only think that it requires to make an element resizable (the way it looks like in the example), but I want to make it possible to detect a change in height only. The element is already (sort of resizable) else I wouldn't be asking this question in the first place, due to the `height: auto;` property. I guess I'll figure out some code to detect a change in height if that's possible in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it only works with Window. The browser fires the resize event if the window size changes (or if you scroll too far on some mobile phones). You would have to create something that would monitor the size of individual elements and fire a custom event.

The [Trigger page](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in their API has some information on triggering custom made events.